# Difficulties Pertaining to Catering to Multiple Phone Screen Sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on an application and am trying to allow it to support multiple phone screen sizes (it will not support anything larger than a Google Pixel 3 XL). Also, just for context, I'm using a ConstraintLayout.

For the background of the layout I'm using an image. On top of the background, I have interact-able elements meticulously placed to match the position they're supposed to correspond with on the background. This, however, doesn't translate well across all displays, as the layout elements and the background become distorted and misaligned. My solution to this was to try to make different layouts for phones which would be applied based on their resolution (layouts were made for phones with these screen dimensions: 1080x1920, 1080x2160, 1440x2560, 1440x2880, 1440x2960).

However, these don't seem to auto-apply to any of the devices I've tested on. I'm assuming this is because phones don't have any specifications and this only really applies to tablets, watches, etc. I just recently thought of transferring everything from my UI into my layout and to just implement everything using ImageViews, but this doesn't work either, since when the phone
screen size changes, all elements lose their proper placement within the screen. I've tried almost everything and can't quite think of anything else to do in order to make my app cater to all screen sizes.

I'll provide one of my more complicated layouts for reference. Really hoping for some help on this one. Thanks!

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/a1440x2960_tt">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/freesansbold"
        android:text="00 : 00 . 00"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetbtn"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="268dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="268dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="264dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/stopbtn"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pausebtn"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="264dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/stopbtn"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goalMinutes"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/freesansbold"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:text="00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splashdebugoutput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goalMilli"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/freesansbold"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:text="00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/goal_dot"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goalSeconds"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/freesansbold"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:text="00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/goal_colon2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_dot"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_bold"
        android:text="."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/goalSeconds"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_colon"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="457dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_bold"
        android:text=":"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tempoSeconds"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_colon2"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_bold"
        android:text=":"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/goalMinutes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minmarker"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:text="M"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/goalMinutes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/goalMinutes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secmarker"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:text="S"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/goalMinutes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/goalMinutes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/millimarker"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="246dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="246dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:text="MS"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/goalMinutes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/goalMinutes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splashdebugoutput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/course"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="233dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="233dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resetbtn"></Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/length"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resetbtn"></Spinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startbtn"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pausebtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.741"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splashdebugoutput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goalMinutes" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tempoSeconds"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="448dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/texthint"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tempoMilliTens"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="448dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/texthint"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/goal_colon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tempoMilliHundreds"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="448dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="0"
        android:maxLength="1"        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/texthint"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tempoMilliTens"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/splitAuto"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleX="1.35"
        android:scaleY="1.35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/course" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/splitManual"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:scaleX="1.35"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleY="1.35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitAuto" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checked1"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="151dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/course" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checked2"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="148dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/length" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checked1u"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="148dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/course" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checked2u"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="152dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/length" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secInput"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="132dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="Sec."
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitAuto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/milliInput"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="132dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="Milli."
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/secInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitAuto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/product_regular"
        android:hint="Time Offset Per Length"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitAuto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="292dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="292dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splashdebugoutput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitManual" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/splitList"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/gray_scroll_style"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtData"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="132dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/debugOutput2"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a lot of hard coded density pixels there. Have you tried using dimen.xml?